# wxpython not working on centos

Tags: python, wxpython

I am simply following the tutorial from [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started#A_First_Application:_.22Hello.2C_World.22)

```
   1 #!/usr/bin/env python
   2 import wx
   3 
   4 app = wx.App(False)  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
   5 frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World") # A Frame is a top-level window.
   6 frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
   7 app.MainLoop()
```

I got an error message at line 4. Here is the error message.

> Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?

```
 uname -a
```

> Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan
>   25 22:07:14 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
python --version
```

> Python 2.7.5

```
pip freeze
```

> wxPython==2.8.12.0
>
> wxPython-common==2.8.12.0

Comment: Is it through ssh that you are trying to run the script?

Comment: wxPython cannot be used on a headless display. You will need X Server or some other UI for it to run on.

Comment: To: @Cory Shay, yes, I am on Mac host and SSH into a local VM that runs CentOS.

Comment: Thanks @Mike Driscoll. Is there a way to show the graph with the setup: Mac host and SSH into a local VM that runs CentOS?

Comment: If the run the wxPython program on the Mac and communicate to CentOS somehow, then yes

Comment: You could possibly do it with [X Forwarding](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine). The concepts within the question would be similar but may vary for Mac OS X.

Comment: Thanks, @CoryShay, could you post your comment as answer so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely need to set up [X Forwarding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12772/161074) in order to get it to work properly.
Quote from answer above by @Giles:

> X11 forwarding needs to be enabled on both the client side and the server side.
>
> On the client side, the `-X` (capital X) option to `ssh` enables X11 forwarding, and you can make this the default (for all connections or for a specific conection) with `ForwardX11 yes` in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5).
>
> On the server side, `X11Forwarding yes` must specified in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5). Note that the default is no forwarding (some distributions turn it on in their default `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), and that the user cannot override this setting.
>
> The `xauth` program must be installed on the server side. If there are any X11 programs there, it's very likely that `xauth` will be there. In the unlikely case `xauth` was installed in a nonstandard location, it can be called through [`~/.ssh/rc`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#SSHRC) (on the server!).
>
> Note that you do not need to set any environment variables on the server. `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` will automatically be set to their proper values. If you run ssh and `DISPLAY` is not set, it means ssh is not forwarding the X11 connection.
>
> To confirm that ssh is forwarding X11, check for a line containing `Requesting X11 forwarding` in the `ssh -v -X` output. Note that the server won't reply either way.